# Is there anyway possible to run the Fitness Fixtures from command prompt?

Tags: java, ant, fitnesse

As of now I am using Jenkins and its Fitnesse plugin to trigger the fixtures. But I need to run the same fixtures from command prompt. Is there any way out like configuring an ANT file?

Comment: what do you mean by fitness fixtures ?

Answer (score 1):

From a command prompt you can do something like:

java -jar \apps\fitnesse\fitnesse.jar -c "MyTests?suite"

See: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine